# responsive fontasize in apex chart data labels

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

Hello everyone I am trying to chang font size on the labels on mobiles only because I have a pie and on mobile the label size too big and looks wonky.
My current setting for the style of the data labels is this

```
          style: {
            fontSize: "15px",
            fontFamily: "DM sans",
            fontWeight: "light",
            
          },
          formatter(val, opts) {
            let labelIndex = [50, 15, 5, 5, 2.5, 12.5, 10];
            const name = opts.w.globals.labels[opts.seriesIndex];

            return [name, labelIndex[opts.seriesIndex] + "%"];
          },
          
        },
```

I know I should add the responsive part somewhere I tried different scooping and place to stick it but works nowhere wondering if im doing something wrong

````
responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 500,
            options: {
              style: {
                fontSize: "10px",
                fontFamily: "DM sans",
                fontWeight: "light",
              },
            },
        }],
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

`responsive` should be added at the top level, in `options`, at the same level as `dataLabels`. Then *its* different `options` should have the same structure as the global `options` they are overriding, specifying at each level only those options that are different from the global options.

An example structure (of course, partial):

```js
const options = {
    dataLabels:{
        style: {
            fontSize: "15px",
            fontFamily: "DM sans",
            fontWeight: "light",    
        },          
    },
    responsive:[{
        breakpoint: 500,
        options:{
            dataLabels:{
                style:{
                    fontSize: "10px"
                    // only options that are changing are needed  
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Here's a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/12r8xayp/).